# gRPC：signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter

Tags: python, multithreading, scrapy, grpc, grpc-python

When I use gRPC to call the scrapy spider interface, I encounter a problem.

First, I use the command `python interface`*`_server.py`to start a gRPC server，then create a new terminal, input the command `python interface_client.py`. *

The output of `interface_server.py` is as follows:

```
PS C:\Users\12948\Desktop\wwas\VSCodeProj\octo-ai-service\octo_ai_service\ai\kg_sjz\grpc\interface> python .\interface_server.py
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "C:\Users\12948\Desktop\wwas\VSCodeProj\octo-ai-service\.venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 513, in _continueFiring
    callable(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\12948\Desktop\wwas\VSCodeProj\octo-ai-service\.venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1314, in _reallyStartRunning
    self._handleSignals()
  File "C:\Users\12948\Desktop\wwas\VSCodeProj\octo-ai-service\.venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\posixbase.py", line 142, in _handleSignals
    _SignalReactorMixin._handleSignals(self)
  File "C:\Users\12948\Desktop\wwas\VSCodeProj\octo-ai-service\.venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1281, in _handleSignals
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, reactorBaseSelf.sigInt)
  File "C:\Users\12948\anaconda3\lib\signal.py", line 47, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
builtins.ValueError: signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter

###########################
request path:https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E5%9D%A6%E5%85%8B
###########################
C:\Users\12948\Desktop\wwas\VSCodeProj\octo-ai-service\.venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\selector\unified.py:83: UserWarning: Selector got both text and root, root is being ignored.
  super().__init__(text=text, type=st, root=root, **kwargs)
```

The output of `interface_client.py`is as follows:

```
PS C:\Users\12948\Desktop\wwas\VSCodeProj\octo-ai-service\octo_ai_service\ai\kg_sjz\grpc\interface> python .\interface_client.py
Enter the name of the target you want to crawl:坦克
Greeter client received: Finish operation: spider, Target: 坦克
```

'坦克' means 'tank'. The spider crawls the Wikipedia page of your entry and saves the text in txt format.

There was no problem the first time the server was requested，although it had some error warnings that I didn't know what they meant. But it does crawl the page down. However, when I asked the server for a second time, the program did not work properly. And the output of  `interface_client.py`is as follows:

```
PS C:\Users\12948\Desktop\wwas\VSCodeProj\octo-ai-service\octo_ai_service\ai\kg_sjz\grpc\interface> python .\interface_client.py
Enter the name of the target you want to crawl:坦克
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\12948\Desktop\wwas\VSCodeProj\octo-ai-service\octo_ai_service\ai\kg_sjz\grpc\interface\interface_client.py", line 32, in <module>
    run()
  File "C:\Users\12948\Desktop\wwas\VSCodeProj\octo-ai-service\octo_ai_service\ai\kg_sjz\grpc\interface\interface_client.py", line 27, in run
    response = stub.Calls(interface_pb2.InterFaceRequest(method=method, args=args))
  File "C:\Users\12948\Desktop\wwas\VSCodeProj\octo-ai-service\.venv\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 1030, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "C:\Users\12948\Desktop\wwas\VSCodeProj\octo-ai-service\.venv\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 910, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)  # pytype: disable=not-instantiable
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNKNOWN
        details = "Exception calling application: "
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer  {created_time:"2023-06-26T07:59:20.907075061+00:00", grpc_status:2, grpc_message:"Exception calling application: "}"
>
```

I don't why that happend. My codes are as follows:

```
# interface_server.py

import grpc
import random
from concurrent import futures
import interface_pb2
import interface_pb2_grpc
import sys
sys.path.append("..\..")
import models

class InterFace(interface_pb2_grpc.InterFaceServicer):
    def Calls(self, request, context):
        if request.method=="spider":
            models.webSpider(request.args[0])
        return interface_pb2.InterFaceResponse(message='Finish operation: {msg}, Target: {tgt}'.format(msg=request.method, tgt=request.args[0]))


def serve():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    interface_pb2_grpc.add_InterFaceServicer_to_server(InterFace(), server)

    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50054')
    server.start()
    print('gRPC server starts，the port is 50054...')
    server.wait_for_termination()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve()
```

```
# interface_client.py

import grpc

import interface_pb2, interface_pb2_grpc


def run():
    channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50054')
    stub = interface_pb2_grpc.InterFaceStub(channel)
    method = 'spider'
    args = []
    item = input('Enter the name of the target you want to crawl:')
    args.append(item)
    response = stub.Calls(interface_pb2.InterFaceRequest(method=method, args=args))
    print("Greeter client received: " + response.message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

```
# interface.proto

syntax = "proto3";

package InterFace;

service InterFace {
    rpc Calls(InterFaceRequest) returns(InterFaceResponse);
}

message InterFaceRequest {
    string method = 1;
    repeated string args = 2;
}

message InterFaceResponse {
    string message = 1;
}
```

I use command

`python -m grpc_tools.protoc --python_out=.  --grpc_python_out=.  -I. interface.proto`to generate

`interface_pb2.py, interface_pb2_grpc.py`

```
# models.py

import os
import sys

from scrapy_job.crawler import fetch_web
import re

def webSpider(item):
    fetch_web(item)
```

```
# crawler.py

import os
import sys
_scrapy_job = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(_scrapy_job)
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from itemSpider.spiders.wiki import WikiSpider
from itemSpider.spiders.baidu import AdsBSpider
import subprocess
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from twisted.internet import reactor

from itemSpider import settings as my_settings

def fetch_web(input):
    crawler_settings = Settings()
    crawler_settings.setmodule(my_settings)
    runner = CrawlerRunner(settings=crawler_settings)
    
    d = runner.join()
    d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
    reactor.run() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

```
# wiki.py

import random
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from itemSpider.items import ContextItem

interval_seconds = 0.2 + random.uniform(0, 2)


class WikiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "wiki"
    allowed_domains = ["wikipedia.org"]
    base_url = "https://zh.wikipedia.org/"

    def start_requests(self):
        # arg1 = urlencode({'qw':self.term})
        # search_url = self.base_url+arg1
        search_url = self.base_url+'zh-cn/'+self.term
        yield Request(url=search_url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        # time.sleep(interval_seconds)
        _url: str = response.url
        print('###########################')
        
        print(f"request path:{_url}")
        print('###########################')
        # print(response.body)
        data=""
        for div in response.css("#mw-content-text > div.mw-parser-output"):
            for text in div.css("div>p *::text").getall():
                data+=text
        
        item=ContextItem()
        item['term']=self.term
        item['url']=_url
        item['context']=data
        yield item
```

```
# items.py

# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

import scrapy


class ContextItem(scrapy.Item):
    term = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
    context = scrapy.Field()
```

```
# pipelines.py

# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html


from datetime import datetime

from itemSpider import utils

# useful for handling different item types with a single interface


class AllPipeline:
    _start = None
    _end = None

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if spider.name == "wiki":
            utils.save_text(item, "wk")
```

```
# utils.py

from itemSpider.items import ContextItem
import json
import os




def save_text(item: ContextItem, str):
    file_path_dir = 'data'
    if not os.path.exists(file_path_dir):
        os.makedirs(file_path_dir)
    filename = os.path.join(file_path_dir, item["term"]+".txt")
    with open(file=filename, mode='w', encoding="utf8") as fp:
        fp.write(item["context"] + "\n")
```

File directory structure is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LLjY.png)